# Combinatorics problem on k sets and partionning a set of numbers, understanding of the proof

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, proof-explanation

The question I'm struggling with is given here :

[Remove any number and the remaining numbers can be partitioned into two subsets of equal sum; prove all numbers are equal.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2920667/remove-any-number-and-the-remaining-numbers-can-be-partitioned-into-two-subsets)

The problem is the following :

> Supposed I have a list of n real numbers, where n is odd. The list is
>   constructed such that I can remove any arbitrary number from the list,
>   and the remaining numbers can be partitioned into two equal-sized
>   subsets with equal sums. Prove that all numbers in the list are equal.

Here is my problem. I understand neither the paper given here : http://www.math.cmu.edu/~lohp/docs/math/mop2012/combinatorics-black-soln.pdf

nor the answer of @Mike Earnest.

I don't understand those points :

- why would be $Mx=0$ ?
- and $M{\bf1}=0$?
- Are you looking in the field given by $\text{mod } 2$ ?
- And finally, why since $x$ is a multiple of $1$, does that mean that all weights are equal?

Thanks for the help! I don't know if asking about another answer is allowed on this media, I hope it is not prohibited :)

Comment: $Mx$ being 0 expresses the fact that the two subsets have the same sum. $M1$ being 0 expresses the fact that the two subsets have the same size.

Comment: The same question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002267/after-removing-any-part-the-rest-can-be-split-evenly-consequences) with several answers. Personally I thought my answer was the clearest, though it didn't get any votes.

Comment: What does the "$k$ sets" in your question title refer to? What is $k$?

Comment: @bof https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080450/combinatorics-problem-on-k-sets-and-partionning-a-set-of-numbers It means a set of size $k$

Comment: Interesting. I'd expect "$k$ sets" to mean that $k$ is the number of sets, and I'd expect "$k$-sets" to mean sets of size $k$. Still wondering what $k$-sets you're referring to; there is no $k$ anywhere else on the page. Wild guess: is $k=(n-1)/2$??

Comment: Well yeah i m talking about $k$-sets you re refering about. There is a little typo mistake. I m referring to the fact that from a sets of size $2k+1$ you re creating two k-sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the linked answer, for each $i$ let $P_i$ and $Q_i$ be disjoint sets whose union equals $\{1,\ldots,n\}\backslash\{i\}$, and $M$ the matrix described there.
Let's write out what matrix equations $M{\bf x}=0$ and $M{\bf1}=0$ mean; the $i$-th coordinate of $M{\bf x}$ is given by
$$M_i{\bf x}=\sum_{j=1}^nM_{ij}x_j=\sum_{j\in P_i}x_j-\sum_{j\in Q_i}x_j,$$
which equals $0$ precisely when the subset sums of $P_i$ and $Q_i$ are equal. So $M{\bf x}=0$ is equivalent to the subset sums of $P_i$ and $Q_i$ being equal for each $i$. Similarly, the $i$-th coordinate of $M{\bf1}$ is given by
$$M_i{\bf1}=\sum_{j=1}^nM_{ij}=\sum_{j\in P_i}1-\sum_{j\in Q_i}1=|P_i|-|Q_i|,$$
which equals $0$ precisely when the subsets $P_i$ and $Q_i$ are the same size.
So $M{\bf1}=0$ is equivalent to $|P_i|=|Q_i|$ for each $i$.

This shows that the problem translates to linear algebra as follows:

> Given a vector $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\Bbb{R}^n$ where $n$ is odd. Show that *if* there exists an $n\times n$-matrix $M$, with entries from $\{-1,0,1\}$ and $M_{ij}=0$ if and only if $i=j$, satisfying $M{\bf 1}=0$ and $M{\bf x}=0$, *then* $x$ is a scalar multiple of ${\bf 1}$.

The last statement, that $x$ is a multiple of ${\bf1}$, is the same as saying that all the $x_i$ are equal; after all, if $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_n$ then ${\bf x}=x_1\cdot{\bf1}$.

To prove this, the linked answer shows that $\dim\ker M=1$. Because ${\bf x}$ and ${\bf1}$ are both contained in $\ker M$, it follows that ${\bf x}$ is a scalar multiple of ${\bf1}$.

Comment: I would love to get some additional graph Theory... couldn't we say that $M$ is the adjacency matrix of an orientation of the complete graph, i.e. of a tournament? Now, do we know the multiplicity of the $0$ eigenvalue of such matrix? we would be done wouldn't we?

Comment: Indeed $M$ is the adjacency graph of an orientation of $K_{n+1}$. The dimension of the kernel of the Laplacian $L=M^{\top}M$ is equal to the number of connected components of $K_{n+1}$, which is of course $1$, so indeed this finishes the proof quite nicely.

Comment: really nice observation and commentary. Thank you very much !